# Why will my raster only display at certain extents?

Tags: raster, arcmap, display, image-pyramids

I have a large raster image which contains the florida keys and has 1 meter by 1 meter resolution.  When I change the extent and zoom in from 1:6,000 and closer, the image is displayed.  When I change the extent and zoom out from 1:8,000 and beyond, the image is black.

This is LiDAR data and my display troubles only occurred after I created a Mean raster (I created a new raster from the mean values of the pixels from the original LiDAR raster)

I set the pyramid structure to -1 for automatic default.

[image: Raster Not Displayed]
[image: Raster Displayed]

Comment: Does your dataset have a coordinate system defined? Is this the same as the dataframe coordinate system?